Robust fit indices not calculating when constraining intercepts
I am investigating measurement invariance in lavaan across 2 groups. The scale has 12 items and 4 factors. The items are on a 5-point likert scale, so I used the ordered command and am following the Wu & Estabrook (2016) method.
The configural model produced normal output with no errors. However, when evaluating threshold invariance, I am getting NAs for the robust fit indices. No warnings or errors were produced. Out of curiosity, I tried flipping the order and constraining loadings first. When I did this, robust fit indices were available. So, it seems specific to constraining intercepts. For reference, I have tried the syntax with and without specifying "WLSMV" as the estimator (as my understanding is WLSMV should be the default when specifying the items are ordered), it doesn't make a difference.
Can anyone point me to why the robust fit indices would not compute when constraining intercepts to be equal across groups?
Configural model syntax
ies3<-'
upe=~ NA*ies3_1 + ies3_2 + ies3_3
epr=~ NA*ies3_4 + ies3_5 + ies3_6
rhsc=~ NA*ies3_7 + ies3_8 + ies3_9
bfcc=~ NA*ies3_10 + ies3_11 + ies3_12
upe ~~ epr + rhsc + bfcc
epr ~~ rhsc + bfcc
rhsc ~~ bfcc
'

items<-c("ies3_1", "ies3_2", "ies3_3", "ies3_4", "ies3_5", "ies3_6", "ies3_7", "ies3_8", "ies3_9", "ies3_10", "ies3_11", "ies3_12")

config<-measEq.syntax(configural.model = ies3, data = ies3data, group="hfss_FI", group.equal="configural", parameterization="delta", ID.fac="std.lv", ID.cat="Wu.Estabrook.2016",
                        ordered=items)
model.config <- as.character(config)
fit.config<-cfa(model.config, data=ies3data, group="hfss_FI", parameterization="delta", ordered=items, estimator="WLSMV")
summary(fit.config, fit.measures=T)

Configural model Output:
lavaan 0.6-19 ended normally after 35 iterations

  Estimator                                       DWLS
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                       132

  Number of observations per group:               Used       Total
    1                                              276         303
    0                                              686         718

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Scaled
  Test Statistic                               218.778     402.833
  Degrees of freedom                                96          96
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  0.585
  Shift parameter                                           28.644
    simple second-order correction                                
  Test statistic for each group:
    1                                           96.052      96.052
    0                                          306.781     306.781

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                             63271.685   26585.675
  Degrees of freedom                               132         132
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  2.387

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.998       0.988
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.997       0.984
                                                                  
  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                         0.962
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                            0.948

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.052       0.082
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.043       0.073
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.061       0.090
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    0.371       0.000
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.000       0.635
                                                                  
  Robust RMSEA                                               0.083
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower                     0.073
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper                     0.094
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA <= 0.050                         0.000
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA >= 0.080                         0.709

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.048       0.048


Threshold model syntax:
#threshold
thresh<-measEq.syntax(configural.model = ies3, data = ies3data, group="hfss_FI", group.equal="thresholds", parameterization="delta", ID.fac="std.lv", ID.cat="Wu.Estabrook.2016",
                      ordered=items)
model.thresh<-as.character(thresh)
fit.thresh<-cfa(model.thresh, data=ies3data, group="hfss_FI", ordered = items, parameterization="delta", estimator="WLSMV")
summary(fit.thresh, fit.measures=T)

Threshold model output:
lavaan 0.6-19 ended normally after 81 iterations

  Estimator                                       DWLS
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                       156
  Number of equality constraints                    48

  Number of observations per group:               Used       Total
    1                                              276         303
    0                                              686         718

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Scaled
  Test Statistic                               229.941     411.621
  Degrees of freedom                               120         120
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  0.612
  Shift parameter                                           35.713
    simple second-order correction                                
  Test statistic for each group:
    1                                          106.799     106.799
    0                                          304.822     304.822

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                             63271.685   26585.675
  Degrees of freedom                               132         132
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  2.387

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.998       0.989
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.998       0.988
                                                                  
  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                            NA
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                               NA

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.044       0.071
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.035       0.064
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.052       0.079
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    0.887       0.000
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.000       0.027
                                                                  
  Robust RMSEA                                                  NA
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower                        NA
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper                        NA
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA <= 0.050                            NA
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA >= 0.080                            NA

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.048       0.048



I am getting NAs for the robust fit indices. No warnings or errors were produced

Is the model-implied polychoric correlation matrix not positive definite?  I would have expected a warning about that, but you can check that each one has a positive determinant with this syntax: sapply(lavInspect(fit.thresh, "cor.ov"), det).
Since you did not provide a reprex, I just ran the ?measEq.syntax help-page examples, and noticed that robust RMSEA, CFI, TLI are all NA for any level of invariance beyond configural.  Like you, I had no warning, the model-implied matrices are positive definite, and robust indices are only NA when thresholds are constrained.  I reported the issue with this reprex on GitHub, so it will eventually be investigated, but not anytime soon.
UPDATE (21 October 2024):
The development version of lavaan (0.6-20.2217) has resolved this issue.
But note that lavaan's default baseline.model= freely estimates thresholds, which means that the incremental fit indices calculated by default are invalid because the default baseline.model= is not actually nested in a model with equality-constrained thresholds.  This is the same issue with continuous variables (discussed in this article), when scalar-invariance constraints are imposed: a baseline.model= with free intercepts is not nested under a scalar-invariance model with equality-constrained intercepts.
If you want to interpret incremental fit indices, you should fit your own baseline model with equality-constrained thresholds, and pass it to the fitMeasures(baseline.model=) argument.
UPDATE concluded

Can anyone point me to why the robust fit indices would not compute when constraining intercepts to be equal across groups?

(when constraining thresholds)
The way to calculate robust fit indices with DWLS estimation involves evaluating a ML fit function at the DWLS solution, which requires a postitive-definite input matrix:
https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2020.1717922
If you look at the pattern of the other RMSEAs, I think you can confidently extrapolate that the robust RMSEA would be lower for the threshold-invariance model.  But change-in-fit-index is not a valid criterion to evaluate measurement invariance.  I recommend conducting a test using a statistic with a known distribution:
lavTestLRT(fit.config, fit.thresh)

If that omnibus $\Delta\chi^2$ test is significant, then you could calculate $\text{RMSEA}_\text{D}$ (or RDR) as a measure of effect size, as proposed in this article: https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000537
You can obtain $\text{RMSEA}_\text{D}$ (and similar ideas for other indices) in the latest version of lavaan using the new fitMeasures(h1.model=) argument
fitMeasures(fit.thresh, h1.model = fit.config, output = "pretty")

However, those robust indices were also NA in my reprex, so I would not expect this to solve that problem for your data.
A significant omnibus tests in other contexts (e.g., ANOVA) would be followed up by post-hoc tests of individual parameters, to detect where which items function differentially across groups. Those tests are difficult to find associated measures of effect size for, but I like the idea of quantifying the impact of DIF on the parameters of interest (e.g., this article using functionality now included in lavTestScore(..., epc=TRUE).  This article does a good job of that, using a series of models that free each item's parameters:
https://doi.org/10.1007/s11136-018-1785-8

I used the ordered command

FYI, when all of your observed variables are to be treated as discretized normal variables, then you can more simply set the argument ordered=TRUE.

Thank you so much for this comprehensive reply. I am really appreciative. I ran the code you suggested and got this:
1                                 0
1.533616e-03     8.114357e-05
The lavTestLRT is not significant (p=.56), which at least supports threshold invariance.
